# Error in openvpn

Tags: linux, openvpn

```
 openvpnas.service - OpenVPN Access Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpnas.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-04-10 09:28:12 UTC; 5h 2min ago
   Main PID: 14649 (python3)
      Tasks: 13 (limit: 1081)
     Memory: 199.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/openvpnas.service
             ├─14649 python3 -c from pyovpn.sagent.sagent_entry import openvpnas ; openvpnas() --nodaemon --logfile=>
             ├─14667 /usr/bin/python3 -c from pyovpn.cserv.wserv_entry import start ; start() -no -u openvpn_as -g o>
             ├─14668 /usr/bin/python3 -c from pyovpn.log.logworker import start ; start()
             ├─14680 /usr/bin/python3 -c from pyovpn.sagent.iptworker import start6 ; start6()
             ├─14682 /usr/bin/python3 -c from pyovpn.sagent.iptworker import start ; start()
             ├─14686 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
             ├─14689 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
             ├─14696 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
             ├─14698 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
             ├─14704 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
             ├─14713 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
             └─14718 iptables-restore -n
```

Why i am getting these errors even openvpn is running fine

Comment: There are no errors in what you have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean these lines

```
openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
```

Those aren't errors. There is just a switch for the `openvpn-openssl` command called `--errors-to-stderr` which appears to be telling the command to send any errors that occur to stderr. The configuration that is calling it is telling it to use that switch. It doesn't indicate that anything is wrong.